# bash-completion (from Homebrew) not completing variables on OSX

Tags: macos, bash, bash-completion

I use bash completion all the time to save typing. However there is an oddity I am unable to figure out how to fix on OSX.

If I install bash-completion using Homebrew (brew install bash-completion) and set it up in .bashrc, the tab key will no longer complete environment variables. Without this installed, environment variable completion works as expected.

For example, I have shortcuts for all my SSH accounts for clients... instead of typing `ssh myuser@somecrazydomain.com` I can just type `ssh $SSHCRAZY` which is much easier to remember.

**Expected behavior:** In the built-in bash in OSX I can type `ssh $SSHC` and hit tab and it completes to the full command as expected. This is what I want.

**Observed behavior:** In bash using the homebrew bash-completion additions, hitting tab has no effect for environment variables.

**Note:** All other extensions added by the bash-completion project are desired (git command completion, etc). I don't want to uninstall it, I just want it to *also* work with environment variables.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `bash-completion` must have defined completion rule for `ssh`. So try add the `-o bashdefault` option in your `.bashrc`. For example, if `complete -p ssh` output like this:

```
# complete -p ssh
complete -F _func ssh
#
```

then you can add this to your `.bashrc` (or `.bash_profile`):

```
complete -F _func -o bashdefault ssh
```

or

```
eval "$(complete -p ssh | sed 's/ssh$/-o bashdefault ssh/')"
```

Answer (score 4):

You might consider using an [SSH config file](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/) (`~/.ssh/config`) to set up your SSH shortcuts instead of using environment variables. You could put into that file:

```
Host crazy
    HostName somecrazydomain.com
    User myuser
```

Then you can just type `ssh crazy`.

Comment: Technically the other answer is the "right" answer to the question as asked, but this is *much* more elegant. I have used the config file for specifying alternate keys and such, but didn't realize that it both provided aliases for hosts and also auto-completed on `ssh` and `rsync` commands. Win!

Comment: @seawolf Technically your question is wrong, this answer is right for all what's your want.

Comment: The example in my question was around ssh, but ssh is not the only case where completion of environment variables was not behaving as expected. The question was about environment variables. This answer is very elegant but it is an answer to a slightly different question than the one I asked.